# Ada: (gpr)install package with multiple shared libraries

Tags: dependencies, ada, shared, gprbuild, gprinstall

I have an Ada library project creating a shared library that has dependencies on other prebuilt shared libraries (c/c++). Unfortunately the prebuilt libraries can’t be installed system wide and I am looking for a project setup without user specific library path’s.

Therefor I want to create a GPR project that “configures/installs” the Ada library and its dependencies with ‘gprinstall’ so the Ada library can be use out-of-the-box in any Ada executable project.

I figured out that I can make a separate “externally_built” Ada library project for every dependency there is and run a recursive gprinstall on the Ada library project. This will work but adds more packages to the Ada environment than I like so I want to know if there is a better/elegant way to include (extra) shared libraries in a Ada project? (1)

Form the Ada (library) project standpoint the external built libraries kinda belong together, so it would be great if they can be bundled together in one package and installed with gprinstall.

Although I am not sure if this is the way to go, I am trying to get the externally built libraries to piggy-bag with the gprinstall of the Ada library project but without success, maybe someone has an idea how to do this? (2) It’s seems gprbuild can only output one object, is this so? (3)

Thanks in advance and for your time,
Ingmar

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful, but Alire does a very good job at isolating and managing dependencies.

Comment: Even though I will look into 'alr'. At the moment I am on GNAT-2021 that, so far as I can see didn't ship with it. Thanks.

Comment: I'l supply you with a more detailed answer.

Comment: @ATL_DEV You forgot to supply the answer :P

Comment: I have for the moment created a 'gpr' project per external (shared) library and that works well.